# cucumber giving null pointer exception with multiple scenario in feature file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

**Test Steps**

```
public class TestSmoke {
        WebDriver driver;
        @Given("^open firefox and start application$")jjj
        public void open_firefox_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://example.com");
            
        }
    **Scenario 1**
        @When("^I click on Login$")
        public void I_click_on_Login() throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Login')]")).click();
            
        }
    
        @When("^enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and valid \"([^\"]*)\"$")
        public void enter_valid_and_valid(String uname, String pass) throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.id("Username")).sendKeys(uname);
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(pass);
            
        }
    
        @Then("^Click on login and User should be able to login successfully$")
        public void Click_on_login_and_User_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.id("loginUser")).click();
            
        }
```

jkjbjkkjhjknjkbjkhjkbjbjbbjbnmbbnmb

```
        **Scenario 2:**
        @Given("^Click on shop for carts$")
        public void Click_on_shop_for_carts() throws Throwable {
            hhjbhbhgjbkjbhlhihjbhbb
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Shop for Parts']")).click();
            
        }
    
        @Given("^select plates$")
        public void select_plates() throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Plates ')]")).click();
            
        }
    
        
        @When("^I click on drsired product$")
        public void I_click_on_drsired_product() throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-itemnumber='PLT01096096046']")).click();
        }
    
        @When("^click on item increment$")
        public void click_on_item_increment() throws Throwable {
            WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'fa fa-caret-up')]"));
            for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
            {
                ele.click();
            }
            
        }
    
        @When("^Click on buy now$")
        public void Click_on_buy_now() throws Throwable {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Buy Now')]")).click();
            
        }
    
        @Then("^Product should be added to the cart successfully$")
        public void Product_should_be_added_to_the_cart_successfully() throws Throwable {
            
            
        }
```

**Feature File**
Feature: Test test Smoke scenario

```
 Scenario: Test login with valid credentials
    Given open firefox and start application
    When I click on Login
    And enter valid "s@yopmail.com" and valid "passw0rd"
    Then Click on login and User should be able to login successfully
    
    
    Scenario: Test shop for cart
    Given Click on shop for carts
    And select plates
    When I click on drsired product 
    And click on item increment 
    And Click on buy now
    Then Product should be added to the cart successfully
```

**Test runner**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(features="features",glue={"steps"})
public class TestRunnr {
```

While i am running this cucumber script its throwing an NullPointer Exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at steps.testmoke.Click_on_shop_for_carts(testSmoke.java:47)
    at ?.Given Click on shop for carts(MyApplication.feature:11)
```

First scenario is executing successfully but second scenario is not executing.I am login in a ecommerce website and try to click on shop for parts .

Comment: Do you have any @After hooks where you close instance of WebDriver?

Answer (score 4):

Each scenario creates a fresh instance of all the step definitions. 
In your case you instantiate the driver in the `Given step public void open_firefox_and_start_application()` so the first scenario is successful.
Now for the second scenario a new instance of your class has a webdriver which is null and you are not calling the earlier step to instantiate it.

You can use a static webdriver, but you will run into issues with parallel tests. If you are planning for parallel tests look up `ThreadLocal` to make sure your webdriver is attached to the specific thread.

Another way could be to move the login tests to a separate file. For the other scenarios move the login steps into the `Background` cucumber tag. This way the webdriver will be instantiated for each scenario. But you will need to decide if you want to keep logged in across scenarios, delete cookies or a new browser for each scenario.

Comment: i got your suggestion but i am completely new to cucumber so i dont have idea how to implement these all......can you share some piece of code that help me out

Comment: Just add the keyword static in front of the webdriver declaration.